# Is there a way to create an image from list of lists of tuples containing RGB values?

Tags: python, list, tuples, python-imaging-library

I am trying to turn a list of rgb values into an image. For the sake of simplicity I will show an example of what I am trying to do instead of my actual code.

I need to turn this list:

```
[[(255, 255, 0), (128, 128, 128), (211, 211, 211)], [(0, 0, 255), (255, 165, 0), (0, 255, 0)], [(128, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (255, 215, 0)]]
```

Into an image using python.

I am trying to do this using the pillow module but because of the nature of the way the rgb values are stored, i'm struggling to understand how I can go about this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`imgshow`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) from matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = [[(255, 255, 0), (128, 128, 128), (211, 211, 211)], [(0, 0, 255), (255, 165, 0), (0, 255, 0)], [(128, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (255, 215, 0)]]
plt.imshow(img);
```

Out:

[image: plt image]

Comment: This seems to work, but the project I am working on needs to be done with the pillow module. I won't mark this answer as correct but thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with a solution for the `pillow` module. I hope you get an answer that completely solves your question.